# DC motor control using optical encoder wheel

Tags: dc-motor, feedback

I want to be able to precisely control a CNC spindle using an optical encoder wheel or hall effect sensor (doesn't matter which at the moment). The problem I'm running into is breaking down the problem into how to provide feedback. I've seen a few posts on this but I'm still very lost. The thing that seems the most sensible solution to me is a "PID Controller" but it involves multiple op amps and they tend to fail quite spectacularly when I work with them.

The way I see the problem there is a "mystery circuit" with one input and one output. The input takes pulses from the hall effect/optical encoder and the output is either high or low (1 or 0). There are three cases I wish to handle:

- Case A: Motor is spinning at correct speed. Output doesn't matter (hysteresis?)
- Case B: Motor is spinning less than correct speed. Output should be high (1)
- Case C: Motor is spinning too fast. Output should be low (0)

Ideally I want to handle this without the use of a microcontroller. I could have sworn there was a way to use a 555 one-shot to "count" input pulses and output high or low based on a set RC parameter, but it's been a long time since I played with that.

Can someone please provide me some direction as to how I might accomplish the above? Is "PID Control" the term I'm looking for here? Also, is there a one-chip solution for doing this sort of thing, since, as stated, op amps and I don't seem to get along very well (I'm open to a simple op-amp circuit with an explanation as well)?

Comment: PID stands for "Proportional-Integral-Derivative".  "... is a control loop feedback mechanism widely used in industrial control systems and other applications requiring continuously modulated control...".  Some might say this is a way to get to where you want to be (i.e. temperature, speed, ect) quickly and stay there better.  Don't know why you don't like processors, it's probably the best way to get what you want.  If you're looking for a turn-key solution, why not just buy a COTS motor speed controller.  I'm sure there are plenty out there.

Comment: How can the "correct speed" output not matter when you don't know that it's running at the correct speed. Not sure you mean hysteresis but rather a dead-band where the output assumes a central position between 0 and 1 when the motor is running within a small tolerance of "correct".

Comment: Oh, you want to know the RPM of the spindle.  Is that is?  I think most wood workers just point an optical RPM gun at the moving part and set the speed control (i.e. they are their own feed back mechanism).

Comment: What do you want to happen if the spindle is too high or low?  Do you want things to respond quickly (if so, how quickly) if the spindle changes speed (ie, when a tool is cutting)?  How is "correct speed" input into the system?

Comment: Perhaps you're looking for abandoned speed-control technology, called **governor**. These were mechanical solutions using no op amps.

Comment: As suggested by @glen, consider reading up on centrifugal governors. There are so many different incarnations that I'm not going to try at providing a list. You can just go look them up and see which of them are closer to what you can achieve. There's no question it would work for you. You don't get the '0' and '1'. (No idea why you'd want that -- it's just on/off control and not PID.) But you will get regulation to the right RPM, which I believe is your real goal. And no MCU!

Comment: The term you’re looking for regarding the 555 circuit is “frequency to voltage converter” - build a f2v circuit and you will have an actionable voltage you can feed an opamp based pid controller with.

Comment: At the moment I'm not so concerned about exact RPMs given an input voltage. I just want to provide an input voltage and have it spin at about the same RPM regardless of mechanical load (theoretically). I'm happy to use an AVR microcontroller but I feel that'd introduce a whole host of other issues, re. clock speed/timing/etc. Yes, I am in fact attempting to make a governor, but without mechanical parts.


The "0/1" approach is to mimic PWM control, since this is a 100v motor that I will be driving with a dedicated variable power supply.